# set appIconBadgeNumber on the app icon with a UILocalNotification simultaneously

Tags: xcode4

I am trying to set the appIconBadgeNumber along with a local notification as
[localNotif setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:count];
but the badge occurs as soon as the application enters the background where as the Notification is fired at its scheduled time.

please help i am a beginner in iPhone development.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the badge when the notification fires. In your app delegate, implement this method:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {
    notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
}
```

Also be prepared for cases when the notification fires while your app is in the background:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)opt {

    // ... 

    UILocalNotification *notif = [opt objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

    // ...

    return YES;
}
```